# How to structure a single page app with knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am mostly wondering how to organize things like modal windows, and dynamic pages like profiles. Should the viewModel only contain one profile view or contain all profiles loaded? This here just doesnt seem very "clean".

```
viewModel = {
  profile: ko.observableArray([
    new ProfileViewModel()
    //... any others loaded
  ])
, createPostModal: {
    input: ko.observable()
  , submit: //do something to submit...
  }
}

<div data-bind="foreach: profile"><!-- profile html --></div>
<div data-bind="with: createPostModal"></div>
```

This way doesn't seem very consistent. Is there anybody who has built a single page app with knockout that can offer some advice? Code samples would be appreciated.

Comment: have a look at http://boilerplatejs.org. This gives you a reference architecture to structure your SPA.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We are just starting down this path at work, and so are not quite sure what we're doing. But here's the idea we have.

The page should be composed of any number of "components," possibly nested. Each component has a view model and one public method, `renderTo(el)`, which essentially does

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModelForThisComponent, el)
```

It also could have the ability to render subcomponents.

Constructing or updating a component consists of giving it a model (e.g. JSON data from the server), from which it will derive the appropriate view model.

The app is then created by nesting a bunch of components, starting with a top-level application component.

---

Here is an example for a ["hypothetical"](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/nookstudy/) book-managing application. The components are `LibraryUI` (displays a list of all book titles) and `DetailsUI` (a section of the app that displays details on a book).

```
function libraryBookViewModel(book) {
  return {
    title: ko.observable(book.title),
    showDetails: function () {
      var detailsUI = new BookDetailsUI(book);
      detailsUI.renderTo(document.getElementById("book-details"));
    }
  };
}

function detailsBookViewModel(book) {
  return {
    title: ko.observable(book.title),
    author: ko.observable(book.author),
    publisher: ko.observable(book.publisher)
  };
}

function LibraryUI(books) {
  var bookViewModels = books.map(libraryBookViewModel);
  var viewModel = {
    books: ko.observableArray(bookViewModels);
  };

  this.renderTo = function (el) {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, el);
  };
}

function BookDetailsUI(book) {
  var viewModel = detailsBookViewModel(book);

  this.renderTo = function (el) {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, el);
  };
}
```

Note how we could make the book details appear in a jQuery UI dialog, instead of in a singleton `#book-details` element, by changing the `showDetails` function to do

```
var dialogEl = document.createElement("div");
detailsUI.renderTo(dialogEl);
$(dialogEl).dialog();
```

Comment: So you are suggesting more of a backbone.js style right? With:

render: function () {
  $(this.el).html(this.template)
  ko.applyBindings(this.viewModel, this.el)
}

Comment: Yeah, to some extent. The trick is realizing that view models are not enough by themselves; you need something like Backbone views to manage the lifecycle of whatever is being rendered. Knockout excels at data-binding, but that's just part of the story that you need to integrate into your component rendering.

Comment: Domenic, you have some really good ideas. We are basically at the same place as you were when you posted this a couple of months ago. I wondered if and how your thoughts on SPA architecture have evolved in this time. How did you decide to manage lifecycle? Did you use Backbone, another library, or roll your own. I would be very interested in what you might share on this topic.

Answer (score 12):

There are 3 frameworks out there that help with creating SPAs using Knockoutjs.

- [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/)
- [Pagerjs](http://pagerjs.com/)
- [KnockBack](http://kmalakoff.github.com/knockback/)

I have used Durandal and I really like it. Easy to use and has a lot of nice configurations so you can plug-in your own implementations.  Also, Durandal is created by the same creator of [Caliburn](http://www.caliburnproject.org/) which was an very popular framework for building Silverlight/WPF applications.

Comment: Durandal is the way to go , especially when you are already utilizing knockout, jQuery and requirejs. There is very little to learn and it saves you from writing all the boilerplate glue to tie these libraries together.

Comment: As a note, I tried out Durandal and found it to be hard to work with on PhoneGap. In the current iteration, PhoneGap has a tough time working with RequireJS (which Durandal depends on). Also, you need to use a third-party JavaScript build tool (i.e. Mimosa, Grunt, etc.) to get it to work on a device. It seems like a great tool, but PhoneGap just isn't ready for it.

Answer (score 6):

Now in 2014, you probably want to use Knockout's component feature and Yeoman to scaffold your initial ko project. See this video: [Steve Sanderson - Architecting large Single Page Applications with Knockout.js](http://vimeo.com/97519516)

Answer (score 3):

**[update april 5, 2013]** at time of writing this answer was valid. Currently I would also suggest the [Durandal JS](http://durandaljs.com/) approach as the way to go. Or check [John Papa's Hot Towel or Hot Towelette SPA templates](http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel/) if you are using ASP.NET MVC. This also uses Durandal.

Original answer below:

I would like to point out Phillipe Monnets 4 part series about Knockout.js to you. He is the first Blogger I encounterd who splits up his example project in multiple files. I really like most of his ideas. The only thing I missed, was how to handle ajax / rest retrieved collections by using some kind of Repository / Gateway pattern. It's a good read.

Link to part 1: http://blog.monnet-usa.com/?p=354

Good luck!

Comment: Mdocter, thank you for sharing this link! It is quite an in-depth article. While it is not based on a single page application, there are very useful ideas and tips. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I just open-sourced the mini SPA framework I put together with Knockout being the major component.

**knockout-spa**
A mini (but full-fledged) SPA framework built on top of Knockout, Require, Director, Sugar.
https://github.com/onlyurei/knockout-spa

**Live Demo:**
http://knockout-spa.mybluemix.net

#### Features

- Routing (based on Flatiron's Director): HTML5 history (pushState) or hash.
- Highly composable and reusable: pick modules/components for a page in the page-specific JS and they will be auto-wired for the page's HTML template
- SEO ready (prerender.io)
- Fast and lightweight (85 KB of JS minified and gizpped)
- Two-tier bundle build for JS for production: common module that will be used by most pages, and page-specific modules that will be lazy-loaded
- Organized folder structure to help you stay sane for organizing and reusing JS, CSS, HTML
- Using Knockout 3.3.0+ so ready for Knockout's flavor of web component and custom tags (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html)
- All documentation are in the major dependencies' own homepages, so that you don't need to completely learn a new framework

  - Knockout http://knockoutjs.com
  - Require http://requirejs.org
  - Director https://github.com/flatiron/director
  - jQuery http://jquery.com
  - Sugar http://sugarjs.com